# Kafka Resiliency (Clustering) setup on single and multiple machines

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, failover, resiliency

I have setup 1 Zookeeper and 3 Kafka Broker (for Redundancy) on a single machine.
I want to know what is the best practice for Kafka Setup on a single machine and multiple machines in a network.
for e.g. if I set up on a single machine how many zookeeper, brokers and partition I should set up.
Or
If I set on multiple machines (N number of machines) then how many zookeeper, brokers and partition I should set up in respect to N.

Answer (score 0):

As the *machine* is the main cause of failures, you gain zero by running thee copies on the same machine.

They will all fail at the same time.

Comment: what is the rules and best practices for partitioning topics...single partition is good or having 1,2,3 etc. partitions in multiple brokers?

Comment: On a single host, you gain nothing by having multiple brokers etc.

Comment: I know; my question is about topic partitioning not multiple brokers on single host....as I know topic partitioning can help consumers work in parallel and boosting throughput. My question is how should we define number of partitions and what are the rules for doing so.

Comment: As I investigated more it is suggested when we have N Consumers it would be better to have also N partitions to have parallelism. But having 2 partitions is not suggested because it may cause Consumer starvation and messages goes to only one partition leaving another partition empty....I am not sure why this occur when having 2 partition....I investigated more and found it somewhat related to Kafka Partitioner mechanism and underlying hashing mechanism that may have collisions. so I am not sure having 2 partitions instead of 1 or 3 is really bad thing!...